# how to get the number of peoples like from facebook

Tags: facebook-fql

i need to get the number of peoples like for the given hotel name in the facebook. In the facebook developer site, i found that FQL (Facebook Query language) [Click here to know about FQL.](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/) But i dont know where i have to use this FQL. Actually from java, i would like to get this number. Is it possible. Hz i can do that. Please post hints for that. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

U can use this adress to get some information about page:
https://graph.facebook.com/IDPage

For IDPage u should type name or id profile from which u want get information. It is JSON and variable name with numbers of people who like site is "likes".
Check it.